# How can run app using Express 4 without "DEBUG=node:* ./bin/www"

Tags: node.js, express, phpstorm, express-4

I'm learning Node.js + Express 4 and command that running my app looks so:

> $>DEBUG=node:* ./bin/www

And what is this command do ?

How can I run my app like this:

> $>node app.js

PS: I need to run under phpStrom and can't set in configuration first command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off I think it is important to understand that an Express app in nothing more than an initiated *Express app object* which is listening on some port (see  ex1). On the first line of this example you can see what is called a `linux hashbang or shebang` which is a line that tells your shell what kind of interpreter it should use to execute the following file. Therefore it is possible to create a file with the node hashbang, remove the .js extension en still be able to execute it using `./{myscript}` where ./ causes it to run.

Now that we got the basics down I am fairly certain you used the express-generator to create your app. Which indeed tells you to run your app using the `DEBUG=node:* ./bin/www`. The `./bin/www/` simply runs the `www` file in the /bin folder. Which is essentially a javascript file with a node hashbang that imports the app instance from `app.js` and initiates and http server on it, which start listening for events. The `DEBUG={name}:*` command is used by `npm debug` [npm debug link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug). It simply tells the package which debug functions it should use. The `*` being a wildcard for: use all of them all (see npm debug package docs for for info).

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get(function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello')
})

app.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('Server started on port:8080')
})
```

Tip if you simply dont like typing the command because it's too long I suggest you to add it to the scripts section in your `package.json`.

```
'scripts': {
    'start': 'DEBUG=node:* ./bin/www'
}
```

You can then run it by using `npm start`

Comment: Very helpful, concise answer touching most of the complexities that I feel are introduced with Express 4 and the separate generator. I do favor its organization over previous versions but I think the barrier to entry has been raised with what they consider to be best practice.

Comment: Will it work on Windows ? Because that DEBUG command is a bit different in Windows, like this : `set DEBUG=node:* & npm ./bin/www`

Answer (score 1):

If someone will have teh same problem as I, I'm posting answer I found:

./bin/www - is linux executable file that incapsultes including your app.js file and http server creating.
And now you can run your app just without "node", just write ./bin/www and click enter.

DEBUG=node:* - not sure how it works, as for me it just swicth to debug mode (I simply cut this)

To run in phpStrorm in Configuration settings, instead of .js file write ./bin/www so you will able to run your app in phpStorm debug environment.